# Radius of Convergence and Alternating Series Confusion

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I have a homework question that asks the following:

> If $\sum_{n=0}^{∞} c_n*4^n$ is convergent, can we conclude that the following series is also convergent?
>
> $\sum_{n=0}^{∞} c_n*(-4)^n$

Now my logic is that we achieve convergence when the series gets progressively smaller and smaller and eventually converges and doesn't go off "to infinity".

Since the negative sign makes this series smaller overall since many terms will be negative, why can't we necessarily conclude that this series will converge? It seems very intuitive to me and was my go-to solution for this question, but I got it wrong.

Thank you for eading.

Comment: What if  $c_n$ has an alternating term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First, one misconception about the alternating sign: $c_n$ could also have arbitrary, alternating, or whatever sign. So your argument fails here.*

If the radius of convergence is *exactly* $4$, then all bets are off: convergence at $R$ does not imply convergence at $-R$ (and vice-versa). For instance, take $c_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{4^n n}$. You have $R=4$, and $$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n 4^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}
$$
which converges, yet
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n (-4)^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} = \infty\,.
$$

*Note: If the radius had been $R>4$, then things would have been good.*

Comment: How do you know that radius of convergence is 4? I tried using the ratio test by taking the limit as n approaches infinity, and I'm left with c_n+1 / c_n multiplied by 4.

Comment: @DeepLearner Based on the assumptions in your question, one cannot conclude it *is* $4$, only that is *at least $4$. But the sequence I give (which does have itself radius $R=4$) satisfies the assumptions of your question, so it is a counterexample.

Comment: Your comment revealed to me the flaw in my conceptual understanding! Thanks so much for the clear explanations.

Comment: @DeepLearner You're welcome!